# Topographic correction in QGIS SAGA error: Input layers do not have the same grid extent

Tags: qgis, remote-sensing, saga, sentinel-2

I have sentinel-2 layer images and one TIN image. I resampled the TIN to same spatial resolution in Layer 4 (10m). Both images are in the same reference system. But when I try to perform topographic correction by SAGA Topographic correction, an error appears: `Input layers do not have the same grid extent`

Comment: Maybe pixels don't match... Why not use sen2cor calling this DEM?

Comment: thank you for the reply. I am a beginner for RS application. Could you explain more?

Comment: [Sen2cor](http://step.esa.int/main/third-party-plugins-2/sen2cor/) is a processing tool for S-2 images to perform an atmospheric correction. You can use a [custom DEM to perform the topographic correction](http://forum.step.esa.int/t/sen2cor-dem-usage/771)